# Firefox 21 stopped playing audios using jPlayer

Tags: firefox, jplayer

Started facing this issue after FireFox latest update to version 21. I need to support both mp3 and m4a file formats, which is working fine in other browsers by setting `{supplied: "mp3, m4a"}`.

I was able to make this work by setting `supplied` to only `{supplied: "mp3"}` for mp3 files, but the problem is, I cannot set this at runtime and hence support both mp3 and m4a formats. And I cannot use flash solution as it doesn't work in iOS browsers.

Is anybody facing similar issue? Any workarounds?

SOLUTION:
I fixed this by forcing jPlayer to use flash by setting `{soulution: "flash"}` only in Firefox. That solved the problem for now.